# colloquial idiomatic translation of: "beating a dead horse"?

Tags: translation

[KeKeNet](http://www.kekenet.com/kouyu/201501/350964.shtml) translates "beating a dead horse" as:

> 多此一举

[ICIBA](http://news.iciba.com/study/bilingual/1562072.shtml) translated it as:

> 无济于事

Are there any other *better* alternatives to this translation for beating a dead horse? Hopefully more idiomatic.

Comment: search web with e.g. 中文：beating a dead horse, get many hits, e.g.:白費口舌，白費力气,旧事重提,“徒劳无功”，“多此一举”，“白费口舌”，“放马后炮" these can be looked up in dictionaries, e.g. 放马后炮 fire belated shots; criticize (make comments) on (about) sth. after it is already over; do sth. which no longer needs to be done; mount on (flog) a dead horse; start firing after the enemy has gone

Comment: What do you mean by 'more idiomatic'? 多此一举 and 无济于事 are both idiomatic...

Comment: @NS.X. Yeah you’re right. Perhaps I mean allegorical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Beating a dead horse' implies 'on and on, endlessly debating or citing a same tired subject' (doesn't matter if the subject is settled or not)"

I think it can be described as '沒完沒了' in Chinese. To be specific 'beating a dead horse' is "沒完沒了地重複相同的話題 " (endlessly repeating the same topic)

Answer (score 0):

You're flogging a dead horse there. He won't listen.
你对牛弹琴。他不听你的话。